# How to check particular EC2 instance in running state is not used (not in use) from longer time in python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This can be checked by using CPU utilized by that instance but is there is any other way to check it as it consumes extra resource charges in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trust Advisor](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/trustedadvisor/) can help you to find out the instances that idle for a long time. following are some of the criteria that Trust advisor uses.

```
1. Idle EC2 instances if CPU < 10% and Network < 5MB    
2. RDS Instances with no connections for 7 days   
3. ELB with No Active backends and requests below 100
```

> If have a Business or Enterprise support plan, you can enable more
> frequent notifications via multiple delivery methods. You can create
> email or push notifications by using Amazon SNS, notifications that
> trigger actions via AWS Lambda, and more. To enable this
> functionality, use CloudWatch Events to create an event with Trusted
> Advisor as a source.
>
> [Source](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/trusted-advisor-notifications/)

I have created a Python lambda function that query Trust advisor would send out an email report of Idle resource based on the above criteria. Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/sudharsans/af23ee7e8919947af83ceb269a40d8db).

Comment: I have wriiten python script for the same but, BTW When you are triggering the lambda function?

Comment: Lambda to would send me a daily report like a crontab job, Please accept the answer if it helped :)